# G Hub LUA script for Scroll Speed

Tags: scroll, lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have Logitech G604 mouse
I want to Scroll with G6 and G5 button with different Scroll Speed is it possible LUA script. if yes then how I search in G-series Lua API but haven't find anything related.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: `I want to Scroll with G6 and G5 button with different Scroll Speed` - Do you mean G5+Wheel = speed 1,  G6+Wheel = speed 2 ?  Or do you mean G5 = scroll up, G6 = scroll down?

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, I mean different then normal mouse wheel for example g5 and g6 act like slow up/down Scroll while holding down.  and i can control the speed via script
Actually I will use it to zoom in and zoom out in 3d application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can invoke `MoveMouseWheel(120)` and `MoveMouseWheel(-120)` to simulate scroll in both directions.

Try this:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      repeat
         MoveMouseWheel(120)
         Sleep(50)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
   end
end
```

Mouse button 5 acts as Scroll Up.

Comment: Is it Possible to repeat Scroll action by holding the g5 key.
Thanks a lot for you response  I tested you script but it's not repeating the Scroll action i need press the key again and again

Comment: What is the GHUB binding/command/macro assigned to your G5 mouse button?

Comment: Nothing I removed it

Comment: You should return standard command for this button.